# What is the best way to create a copy of a Map using pass-by-value?

Tags: java, dictionary, copy

If I have a Java map with 100s of values in it, and I wanted to create another copy of it using this code :

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Vector<String>> map1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Vector<String>>();
LinkedHashMap<String, Vector<String>> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Vector<String>>( map1 );
```

Then if I change any value in any Vector entry for map1 it will be affected in map2 also. I do  not want that. I want map2 to be totally independent on map1.

What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, you'll need to clone each vector:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Vector<String>> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Vector<String>>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Vector<String>> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
    Vector<String> clone = new Vector<String>(entry.getValue());
    map2.put(entry.getKey(), clone);
}
```

You don't have to go any deeper than that though, of course - because `String` is immutable.

(Any reason you're using `Vector` rather than `ArrayList`, by the way?)

Comment: I am using a Vector just an example :) ... I use ArrayList in real code of course.

Comment: I think you mean "map1.entrySet()" in line2, to loop on the entries.

Comment: @Brad: Yes, I've changed to use `entryset()`. Why would you give an example mixing the pre-Java2 collections with the Java2+ collections if you don't have such an odd mix in your real code?